# Changing a button into a card on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to turn a button, into a card when in mobile view. I've never done this before, but the code below seems like it should work.

What am I missing?

```css
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dates {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}          
} 
   .dates {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dates">
 Hello
</div>
```

Comment: There's no `button`. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: that works when I try it - I see the rounded edge and the shadow on smaller resolutions, can you make a fiddle

Comment: @chazsolo, I mean button "like" - not an actual button. In the media section, it's the code for a bog standard card, outside "media" it's code for a bog standard button. When on small devices, like mobiles, I just want my "hello" within a card, on desktops, I want it in a button-like object. Please tell me if you don't understand what I mean, I could maybe find an example.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky, I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/25749n4t/ for me, it stays as a button even when the screens small. It doesn't switch to a card.

Comment: fiddle works too.. how are you changing the resolution, make sure it goes below 767 for your tests.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky, I get what you mean. It's defo doing something, the shape is slightly changing... but it's still green and so on. I need to remove all css from the standard version when it's below 767. - Sorry, I should have been clearer

Comment: so just include the rules you want to change in the media query too. Like `backgound-color:#fff` - to revert the background to the default, also make sure you do switch the `@media` rules to come after the original ones (as Friday Ameh points out)

Answer (score 0):

Make the media query class come below. like this. view it on full page to see the effect. Hope this helps.

```css
      
       .dates {
        background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .dates {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        transition: 0.3s;
        width: 40%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding:100px;
    }          
    }
```

```html
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="dates">
     Hello
    </div>
```

Comment: You are right that the second rule overwrites the first, but the properties that are changed don't conflict, so this has no effect in this situation